# Retrieving values from hashmap and adding them to a string

Tags: java, android, string, hashmap

I am basically trying to make a string consisting of all the values in my `hashmap`.

For example `String finalOutcome = "forename=Bob&surname=Marl"` and the hashmap would be:

```
Hashmap<String, String> maps = new Hashmap<String, String>();
maps.put("forename", forename);
maps.put("surname", surname);
```

My app/program keeps crashing when I am trying to add the values in my hashmap to get the `finalOutcome`. This is my code, and also how do I do it so that `&` sign does not come after the last value in the hashmap?? I pass this hashmap into another method in another class as follows:

```
public addMapValues(Hashmap<String, String> maps){
    for(int i=0; i<maps.size(); i++){
        finalOutcome += maps.get(i) + "&";
    }
}
```

It's just that bit that is causing me a huge headache and I am sure someone here can fix this almost instantly (yes, I am not good with Java)

Would greatly appreciate some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use a `StringBuilder` to concatenate strings in a loop.
2. Consider Guava's [map joiner](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html#withKeyValueSeparator(java.lang.String)).
3. Your code doesn't work because you're trying to lookup values by index instead of by key. Maps aren't indexed. If you want to iterate over the values, you should use `Map.entrySet()`.

Example with Guava:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
String result = Joiner.on('&').withKeyValueSeparator("=").join(map);
```

Example with loop:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    sb.append('&').append(entry.getKey()).append('=').append(entry.getValue());
}
String result = sb.length() > 0 ? sb.substring(1) : "";
```

Example with Java 8 streams (based on another answer that was deleted from some reason):

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
String result = map.entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> e.getKey() + "=" + e.getValue())
        .collect(Collectors.joining("&"));
```

Comment: Mate you are a genius, so I am getting the string BUT it is in the reverse order so it is `surname=Marl&forename=Bob`. How do I change this order? If this can be done then I can relax for a bit

Comment: `HashMap` does not keep an order. If you want to maintain insertion order, use `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: @SamuelGeorgeszusz, on a separate note, if you're building a GET request, the parameter order shouldn't matter.

Comment: You are a LEGEND mate. It works now. If you don't mind could you please explain the last line `String result = sb.length() > 0 ? sb.substring(1) : ""; Other then that I will upvote as of now :)

Comment: @SamuelGeorgeszusz, `substring(1)` trims the leading `&` from the result. The `length()` check is to make sure we don't get an out of bounds exception if the map (and therefore the builder) was empty.

Comment: Thanks - I have accepted your answer as I have learnt something out of it. Never knew that `LinkedHashMap` was different to `HashMap`. By the way is there another way to write the last line? Because I know the way you wrote is is effective but I'm just curious

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a `StringBuilder` object

```
StringBuilder finalOutcome  = new StringBuilder  ();

for (String name: maps.values()) {
    finalOutcome.append (name).append("&");
}

return finalOutcome.toString ();
```

Consider using https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values()
to get the data out of the Map

Also, please be aware that you are using the same `key` if you are looping i.e. `forename`, so if you were to add a new person, they would replace the existing person in your map.

Comment: For some reason I am getting `null&null&`

Comment: I still don't get how to do this :/

Comment: see the link.  Did you try looking?

Comment: @ScaryWombat, you're missing the elephant in the room. See point 3 in my answer.

Comment: @shmosel Wombats don't like Elephants - too big.